Distance Measure for Two Collections of Points Accounting for Rotation/Reflection/Translation?
I want to obtain the "distance" between two latent spaces, i.e. two collections of points on a Euclidean space.
Are there any such measures that exist? Especially considering they need to account for the possible rotation/reflection/translation of the spaces.
As an example, I have the following two spaces or collections of points:



If I then take my z1 and translate it by a certain amount, like so:



I would like the ideal distance/dissimilarity measure to show that the distance between z1 and z1_trans is 0 because one is a direct translation of the other, and so, as a space or collection of points, they are identical.
On the other hand, there should be some positive value for the distance between z1 and z2 as they are not directly related, i.e. one is not computed using the other in terms of rotations/reflections/translations.
Does such a measure exist?
